# QGIS Graduated renderer for symbols - combining the color AND size methods

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

I want to add symbols with a graduated color in addition to symbol size for point features. Just as important, I want this to also be showing on the Legend in my layout. Answers to similar questions include advice for rule-based manual creation - but I'm hoping someone has an automated approach (plugin or script).  I want a legend that looks like this:

[image]

Note that the bin values here do not matter - what is important is that the color AND the size are both increasing. All of the advice on the net uses Data Defined Overrides on size to get the different sizes and then using "Advanced" Data defined size legend. Which gives a final legend that looks like this:

[image]

Again the bin class values are unimportant. I don't want this or any other manual approach (Rule or DDO). It would be great if there was a **Method** option in the graduated renderer called "size and color" (in addition to the current separate options) or an ability to specify a sub-renderer for a method like size, or if the uncollapsed version of the of Data defined legend size would permit a graduated color value, etc. I don't think this exists, so I'm wondering if someone has code or any ideas?

Comment: Are these for a point symbol layer? If you only have a small number of categories, what's to stop you from just defining them in a rule-based renderer?

Comment: This symbology is for points - and rule-based is manual - that is what I'm trying to avoid. The ability to apply a classification like Jenks on color value, and also a size method is available in QGIS. There should be no need to repeat steps in rules for which algorithms are already available. However, this still does not answer the question - I want a method (if it exists) that provides a single representation of that symbology in the legend. This kind of symbology is available with a single click in ESRI products, and the legend combines value and size (like example 1).

Comment: Remember to add/edit any extra detail in the comments back into the question (the comments are transitory). I suspect you'll find that it's not available in QGIS yet, and that it's being done manually - but you can add it as a feature request (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your advice - I have done both on the assumption I haven't missed an existing option. A programmatic automation would still be helpful!